# Random Sampling from a dataset

Tags: random, stochastic, stochastic-process

I have financial data with values like: "Volume", "Profit/Loss", "Cost", etc

Now, it is safe to assume that every record in this data set is a "realization" or outcome of a single random variable, hence we may model this dataset as a set of iid random variables.

Now, I want to leverage this data set to model the underlying distribution of this random variable.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What programming languages do you want to use? What method do you want to use? What do you already know how to do? Currently, the question is so vague I would recommend reading a book on statistics.

Comment: programming language is largely irrelevant. Method is what I'm asking about.

I am a Mathematician and I can code in almost any programming language. The question is what is the best approach for fitting the distribution of a random variable based on observations of outcomes of that random variable.

I have read plenty of books on Statistics, but I am not a statistician

Comment: The best approach depends on what you want to achieve and also on the characteristic of your data (e.g. the number data points you have). If you don't know any more clear requirements, start with any methods and once you run into a short-coming of it, you will understand your requirements better. For example, use Monte Carlo to fit your random variable in a Bayesian framework.

Comment: OK, cool thanks. I was thinking MC in Bayesian framework made the most sense. Thought maybe there was something exotic that I could look into as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you like a Bayesian approach and programming in Python, I can recommend [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/) and the book [Bayesian Methods for Hackers](http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/). Chapter 1 talks you through how to estimate a random variable from some data using this library.